# How to know when to put closing tag on nested elements

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm converting the following xml to html:

```
<rule>
    <condition type="AND">
        <condition type="AND">
            <condition type="NOT">
            </condition>
        </condition>
    </condition>
</rule>
```

From this structure, you can infer that a condition can have other condition's (or not as is the last condition).

I'm trying to make the same structure in html and not sure when/how/where to put the closing tags for conditions that have conditions inside of them.  This is the output I'm currently getting but I would like it to be as the output above:

```
<rule>
    <condition type="AND">
    </condition> 
        <condition type="AND">
        </condition> 
            <condition type="NOT">
            </condition> 
</rule>
```

Here's my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        &lt;rule&gt;
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//condition" />
        &lt;/rule&gt;
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="condition">
        <xsl:variable name="margin-left"><xsl:number value="(count(ancestor::condition) + 1) * 20" />px</xsl:variable>
        <ul class="list-unstyled" style="margin:0px;margin-left:{$margin-left}">
            <li>
                &lt;condition type="<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>"&gt;<br />
                &lt;/condition&gt;
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select=".//condition"` has the effect of flattening out the hierarchy, as you're selecting all `condition` elements at all levels into a single list.  Instead, you need to start by applying templates to just the top-level `condition`:

```
<xsl:template match="/rule">
    &lt;rule&gt;
    <xsl:apply-templates select="condition" />
    &lt;/rule&gt;
</xsl:template>
```

and then have the `condition` template handle the recursion by applying templates to its own children, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="condition">
    <ul>
        <li>
            &lt;condition type="<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>"&gt;<br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="condition"/>
            &lt;/condition&gt;
        </li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

(I've omitted the styling part, you can sort that out yourself in your full stylesheet once you have the concept of using recursion - in fact, if you use padding rather than margin you may not need the whole counting of ancestors trick at all since each `ul` nests within the previous one).

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much.  You were right on padding as well.